# applying hover only when overflow

Tags: css

I am trying to apply a hover style only when overflow taken place.
For example:

```
.email{
    overflow:hidden;
 }

 /*apply only when email is too long*/
 .email:hover{
    overflow:visible;
    background-color:red;
 }
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Thanks for answering.

Edit:
  I have added a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/mQA4L/ do demonstrate what I want to do.

Comment: I think you could use Javascript to do this

Comment: Can you add something to jsFiddle.net and show your problem?  It is easier that way to understand the issue you are having.

Comment: So the visibility is really irrelevant, as an email that is short, if it changes to `visible` display will do "nothing." In other words, as far as visibility goes, [what you have works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/mQA4L/3/). However, is it that you only want the background color to come up on hover if the email is too long?

Comment: Yes, I am setting the background because I want it to cover other contents. When the email content is not overflowing, there is no need to change background color when mouse hover over.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with pure CSS you will have to use javascript and check if your email is to long.

EDIT:

```
$(function(){
    $('.email').hover(
        function() {
            var width = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
            if (width > 50) {
                $(this).addClass('overflowBg');
            }
        },
        function() {
            $(this).removeClass('overflowBg');
        }
    );
});
```

here is a working example, hope I got you right http://jsfiddle.net/mQA4L/25/